# Esconder menu mobile depois de clicar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Estou com problemas na hora de ocultar o menu no modo mobile responsivo.
Há alguma coisa errada, quando clico no link o menu some, porém quando vou clicar para abrir novamente está dando um bug, abre e fecha rapidamente. O que pode ser?

```
$('.navBar li a').click(function() {
    $('nav #menu-toggle:checked ~ ul').slideUp('fast');
});

$('nav .label-toggle').click(function() {
    $('nav #menu-toggle:checked ~ ul').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Link do projeto: https://codepen.io/lucas-guse/pen/KeJBaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Depois dos seus comentários o seu problema ficou mais claro. Na verdade que faz o menu expandir e recolher é essa regra CSS `nav #menu-toggle:checked ~ ul` então o que vc precisa é fazer com que se o link do menu for clicado o menu se recolha alterando o estado `cheked` do input.

Para isso vc precisa fazer um `.trigger('click')` no seu `input:checkbox`, não precisa usar os métodos `slideToggle` etc, pois que vai fazer esse efeito é o sue CSS `#menu-toggle:checked`, para entender melhor veja o código abaixo.

```js
$('.navBar li a').click(function() {
    $('#menu-toggle').trigger('click'); 
});
```

```css
.navBar {
 position: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  background:#000F23;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 42px;
  margin: 45px 20px ;
  width: 187px;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2%;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  min-width: 40%;
}
nav ul a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
nav ul a:hover {
  color: #AAA;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 17px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Brandon Grotesque';
    font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

nav ul li:last-child a{
    padding: 6px 17px;
    border: 2px solid;  
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #00E4D9;
}

#menu-icon { display: none; /* hide menu icon initially */}

nav ul li:last-child a:hover{
    color: #00ABAF;
}

nav #menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}
nav .label-toggle {
  display: none;
}
nav .wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav nav ul a {
    color: #FFF;
  }
  nav ul {
    background-color: #000F23;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;

  }
  nav li {
    color: #53354A;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 1em 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav #menu-toggle:checked ~ ul {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100vh;
    visibility: visible;
    background:#000F23; 
  }
  nav .label-toggle {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFF 0%, #FFF 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 40%, #FFF 40%, #FFF 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 80%, #FFF 80%, #FFF 100%);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    width: 35px;
  }
  nav .wrapper {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navBar">
  <nav class="wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
      LOGO</div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" />
      <label for="menu-toggle" class="label-toggle"></label>
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
      <li><a href="#funcionalidades">Funcionalidades</a></li>
      <li><a href="#planos">Planos</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="cadastro.html">Inscrever-se</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</nav>
```

**OBS:** Vc não deveria usar uma `<nav>` dentro da outra, o correto seria um `<header><nav></nav></header>` ou colocar a classe `.wrapper` na `nav` de fora assim evitando usar `<nav><nav></nav></nav>`

Comment: Mesmo usando .slideDown o bug continua ao usar o menu responsivo ao clicar pela segunda vez no hamburguer. Abre e fecha rapidamente.

Comment: @LucasGuse então seu problema pode ser com a versão do jQuery ou outra coisa influenciando no seu código, repare que se vc executar o modelo na minha resposta ele funciona 100% pode clicar quantas vezes quiser...

Comment: O seu também não está funcionando para mim e já testei em outro computador. Abra o menu e clique em um link e o menu fecha, mas ao abrir o menu novamente ele abre e fecha rapidamente, funcionando somente se clicar outra vez. Está sempre alternando.

Comment: @LucasGuse agora deu para entender melhor. o que vc precisa é que clicando em algum link do menu ele se recolha, e clicando no ícone do menu também. Dei uma editada na resposta e no código, da uma olhada agora.

Comment: Sensacional, não conhecia esse recurso. Agradecido demais!!